# Tree ID: Tall trunk with thin canopy

Tags: identification

I saw these trees in southern Sydney (near Dolls Point).

They have tall trunk and relatively thin canopy.

[image]

[image]

One more picture from different angle and time:

[image]

Comment: A closeup of a leaf, even one that has fallen to the ground would help

Answer (score 2):

Consider Pinus pinea,  "Stone pine" or "Mediterranean pine".